# How to change current page title?

Tags: javascript, sharepoint-2013

This is my simple code. `currentItem.update();` doesn't work and I have no idea why. Can you help me please?

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    context = new SP.ClientContext.get_current();
    web = context.get_web();
    list = web.get_lists().getById(_spPageContextInfo.pageListId);
    currentItem = list.getItemById(_spPageContextInfo.pageItemId)
    context.load(currentItem);
    context.executeQueryAsync(onQuerySucceeded, onQueryFailed);

    function onQuerySucceeded() {
        currentItem.set_item('Title', 'Test');
        currentItem.update();
    }

    function onQueryFailed(sender, args) {
        alert("Error");
    }

})
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no easy answer, it depends on the master page... if the master page is set to show a page's property as it's title, then that solution should work. For example, if it has something like:

```
<title><SharePoint:ListItemProperty runat="server" Property="Title"/></title>
```

Otherwise, it may have the title defined statically, in which case, it won't use the property.

Comment: Thx for answer. I need to change it using javascript.

Comment: Like I said, you can only change it using JavaScript if the master page (or page) is set to show the title as coming from the Title property of the page.